# Сбербанк апи QR оплата

Tags: api, qr

есть такой проблему нужно подключить сбербанк оплата по QR коду не как не могу в документациях найти на какому адресу отправить запрос и получит url для запроса может кто то знает
заранее спасибо

Comment: Позвоните в Сбербанк на горячую линию, вам расскажут или дадут ссылку на документацию. Это самый правильный вариант )

Comment: Да согласен самый правильный вариант, но самый последний вариант, я не из России ))

Comment: Не имеет значения откуда вы, не получив документации и не заключив договор со сбером вы не получите своего QR или очень быстро получите бан за попытку эмуляции их клиентского приложения :)

Comment: Тогда идите на сайт сбера и ковыряйте его, вдруг там инструкция есть

Comment: @SwaD выдается после заключения договора :)

Comment: Спасибо Вам, позвоню им посмотрю что скажут